# How can I overlay to raster data and create new raster in Arcgis pro

Tags: overlay, raster, arcgis

I would like to overlay 2 raster data of the water surface area in Arcgis Pro.

I have 2 raster data of seasonality water surface and monthly water surface both have 1 band.

- The first one is the number of months that water area is detected. It is classify by 0 - 12 which is 0 month of water detected, 1 month of water detected, 2 months and so on until 12 months.
- The second one is the water yearly classification which classify with 0 - 3. 0 is no observation, 1 is not water are, 2 is seasonality water area, and 3 is permanent water.

Some of the water area detected with 9-12 months are permanent water surface in my context. So, I would like to overlay my second raster data with value of 3-permanent water on the first raster data.
[image: the expect outcome]

I have tried mosaic into new raster but the result is the not what I expect.
I want to have the area of the permanent water replace in the first raster data of 8-12 months water detected in some area and reclassify the value of the replacement into 12.